# accessing localhost from android device over wlan

Tags: php, apache, magento, xampp

I am working on a website in magento, I am trying to access my website on my android phone. I have done all the things like activating port 80, allowing all devices under **httpd.conf** 
Then I created wlan on my laptop and connect my phone with it, I enterd my ip on web browser, it opens the dashboard of xampp server, but I can ony access the dashboard folder of htdocs, my project is in magento folder.
When I try to access that like putiing ip **192.168.173.1:80/magento** it redirect my page to **127.0.0.1/magento** and msg displays web page not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your magento installation is hooked to the 127.0.0.1 base url. You would have to change this, either when you want to test your website on your phone or temporarily.

You can change you base_url to the new one `192.168.173.1:80`. Since thats the url you want to access it via. Try it with and without the port number `:80` in case of errors.

You can check out this article https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_configure_magento_to_work_with_a_new_domain/ or this https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-change-magento-base-urls.html

All the best

Comment: i tried changing my base url ,still when i try to access it on my phone 192.168.173.1:80/magento it is redirecting me to the new base url and showing error webpage not available and ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: What is the new base url you changed it to?

Comment: i added localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: No change it to the new ip you need... localhost isnt accessible straight from your mobile... Use the ip instead... 192.168.173.1:80 Would also update my answer to reflect... Try it with and without the port number in case of errors.

Comment: i accidently remove the ip and set the url to "/magento".
my magento admin pannel is not able to load how do i change the base url no
also change the base url from phpmyadmin core_conf_data. bte it had no effecect .i enterdthe change url and it is giving me error

Comment: You can use this link to see how to change it via phpmyadmin https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-change-magento-base-urls.html

Comment: i did change the url via phpmyadmin but it say flus the magento cache i am not able to flush as the page is not loading giving error web page not available

Comment: To clear the cache, simply delete everything from the /var/cache directory and then reload your website in your browser. To clear all sessions, you can also delete everything from the /var/session folder within your Magento installation directory.

Comment: done! my website is now opening in my phone ,but why it is loading so slow